# Problems connecting my PS Vita to internet with my router

Tags: ps-vita

Im trying to connect my PS Vita to internet with my router, but Im having lot of trouble. The connection to the router seems to work ok, but internet is not working. When I run the "Internet Connection Test", I get this:

```
Obtain IP Address    Successful

Internet Connection  Successful

PSN Sign-in          Failed

Error code : c2-11003-5
```

The WWW Browser doesnt work either. What am I missing? My Android phone, my laptop and all the other devices Ive connected to the router worked alright out of the box.

Comment: Do you get an error code?

Comment: Yes, Ive updated the question

Comment: did you try updating the machine? that might work, otherwise try checking your psn password etc.

Comment: its not just the PSN password. the WWW browser doesnt work either

Comment: I found this thread in a support forum: http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/Support-General/ZyXel-P-660HW-D1-v2-Modem-router-all-in-one-Nat-type-3-woes/td-p/30879154, it's about a PS3, do you have any other sony devices (like a PS3) that connect to PSN?

Comment: I have a PS3 but not in this house :(

Comment: Since I saw that this was bumped and never saw it to begin with - apparently this was a problem a lot around the time that this was posted.  System Update to a current version should make it a LOT more reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked around and found some people who had similar issues. The support officer suggests turning off the 'Disconnect Wi-Fi Connection Automatically' setting under WiFi settings.

Link to support post: http://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-Vita-Technical-Help/C2-11003-5/m-p/17735396

If this doesn't work then honestly you can only do a few things:

1. Try to connect to PSN using another sony product like a PS3. Just going to the website wouldn't be as effective but is worth a shot to see if you can log into PSN from your browser. (In case it's blocked for some reason)
2. Try changing the router settings such as allowing the ports PSN requires, disabling firewalls (Only temporarily, to see if it's the cause), enabling PNP and check for other security settings. If you can't get into your router, try basic stuff like Admin/pass or Administrator/password, you might get lucky otherwise, you need the password
3. Try connecting off of another router. This might be hard to do but try to connect to PSN off of another network or router. Go to some place with free wifi and try connecting through there. If you still can't connect then it's a setting on your vita
4. When all else fails, contact their technical support. Yeah they're gonna run you through what I said but they may know something I don't.

The error is a general network error and it's  hard to track down the exact cause. So trying a lot of solutions and trying to narrow it down is really the only way to go at it.

Comment: That didnt work :( on or off, result is the same

Comment: The error code means it's a general network error, can you give anymore information? Whats your technical experience with routers so I know how to frame my answers.

Comment: I know about opening ports, if thats what you mean. Unfortunately my ISP didnt give me the password to the 192.168.1.1 control panel, so I cant really operate the router. I hope the solution doesnt pass through there

Comment: Unfortunately it likely may, what is your ISP and what kind of router did they give you? (I have comcast and they gave me their "Comcast router"). I'm betting it may have to do with your router settings not allowing something especially if you can't get into it. Their default settings can often be too secure in certain areas and not secure enough in others.

Comment: My ISP is Telefonica (Movistar) and the router is a Zyxel p-660HW-D1

Comment: I'm at work right now, as soon as I get home I'll take a look at your router type (Likely won't matter but it might be a known issue) and see if I can't make a list of things you can try

Comment: its weird an ISP would give you a router you can't control.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and tried all sorts, setting up DMZ, enabling uPNP, switching off firewalls... all to no avail. Bizarrely I could connect to the internet fine and i could connect to PSN using next door's wifi. The solution for me was dead simple...

On the vita, in: settings>network>Wifi settings; the second from last option "Disconnect WiFi connection automatically" needs to be ticked. Makes no sense to me but it worked.

Comment: Indeed that was the solution. No idea why either.

Answer (score 0):

Just uncheck the "use wifi in power save mode" option. :)

Answer (score -2):

Guys the way to fix this is as follow:

Go to your settings, network, wifi settings, then click on the network you having issues with, click on advanced settings, Change DNS Settings from automatic to manual. By Primary DNS type in 4.2.2.2 and by Secondary DNS type in 4.2.2.1 then click on ok. Connect to the Network again. Click on it and run the Internet Connection Test....it will work:)

Comment: Setting DNS is not a guarantee that it will work.  According to the symptoms, DNS isn't anywhere near the problem.

Comment: Frank this is the solution...try it....

Comment: How do you know that's the solution?  There's nothing in the question, nor your answer, that would point to DNS being the problem.  If you think it is, what tells you that it is?

Comment: This was the only solution that works....and this is to be do be done on the vita settings....not the router.

Comment: Because ive tested it on various ps vita's and various networks. It worked every time. Do you even have a vita?

Comment: Yeah, I do have a Vita.  I even have a PS TV. And this wasn't needed in any sense.  DNS is rarely the issue, and from what the question states, it certainly isn't the issue here.

Comment: Watch "how to fix an internet connection problem on the …" on YouTube - how to fix an internet connection problem on the …: http://youtu.be/_AjV5vKrFgA

Comment: Well this was said by sony to be a simple change of settings and your issue is solved. I have a ps2, ps3, ps4, psp, psvita, ps tv, xbone, xbox 360, that means nothing. The fact is I could connect any of my devices to my router but only the vita did not want to go online. I searched high and low and this solution worked for me. Maybe you have a different issue. My issue was exactly as the question above says and I quote "Problem connecting my ps vita to internet using my router" thats the solution. Live with it and dont try troll